# Responsive clip-path SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I'm trying to mask element with SVG by using the css property `clip-path`, like this image.

[image]

The expect is that the circle at `top-left`, `top-right`... is fixed size(like 20px), but the size of the SVG is same with the container.

If container's size is fixed, clipPath will be

```
<clipPath
  d="M20 0
  A20 20 0 0 1 0 20
  V180
  A20 20 0 0 1 20 200
  H180
  A20 20 0 0 1 200 180
  V20
  A20 20 0 0 1 180 0
  Z" />
```

If container's size is `auto`, and clipPath add `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`, the size of circle will not be fixed.

So what should I do?

Comment: I guess you could construct the clip path dynamically every time the container is resized.

Comment: @RobertLongson In that case, do I have to use js api like `MutationObserver`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver perhaps

Comment: can you use percentages when defining the path?

Comment: @cloned you could but it wouldn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build it using CSS and keep the same size for your circles:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:5px;
  background:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800.jpg) center/cover;
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(circle 20px at top    left ,transparent 97%,#fff 100%) top    left,
    radial-gradient(circle 20px at top    right,transparent 97%,#fff 100%) top    right,
    radial-gradient(circle 20px at bottom left ,transparent 97%,#fff 100%) bottom left,
    radial-gradient(circle 20px at bottom right,transparent 97%,#fff 100%) bottom right;
  -webkit-mask-size:51% 51%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask:
    radial-gradient(circle 20px at top    left ,transparent 97%,#fff 100%) top    left,
    radial-gradient(circle 20px at top    right,transparent 97%,#fff 100%) top    right,
    radial-gradient(circle 20px at bottom left ,transparent 97%,#fff 100%) bottom left,
    radial-gradient(circle 20px at bottom right,transparent 97%,#fff 100%) bottom right;
  mask-size:51% 51%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="box" style="width:400px;">

</div>
```

With some CSS variables to easily handle it:

```css
.box {
  --r:20px; /*radius of the circle */
  
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:5px;
  background:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800.jpg) center/cover;
  
  --g:transparent 97%,#fff 100%;
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(circle var(--r) at top    left ,var(--g)) top    left,
    radial-gradient(circle var(--r) at top    right,var(--g)) top    right,
    radial-gradient(circle var(--r) at bottom left ,var(--g)) bottom left,
    radial-gradient(circle var(--r) at bottom right,var(--g)) bottom right;
  -webkit-mask-size:51% 51%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask:
    radial-gradient(circle var(--r) at top    left ,var(--g)) top    left,
    radial-gradient(circle var(--r) at top    right,var(--g)) top    right,
    radial-gradient(circle var(--r) at bottom left ,var(--g)) bottom left,
    radial-gradient(circle var(--r) at bottom right,var(--g)) bottom right;
  mask-size:51% 51%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="box" style="width:400px;--r:40px">

</div>
```